# Why does this field_update_instance() call not preserve all settings?

Tags: entities, commerce

I'm working with Commerce + Addressfield (and Commerce Addressbook). In a `hook_update_N` I want to configure sensible defaults for the site, but one of them (`default_country`) refuses to stick. Why is that?

```
/**
 * Set some defaults to commerce_customer_address field.
 */
function example_update_7117(&$sandbox) {
  if ($field_instance = field_info_instance('commerce_customer_profile', 'commerce_customer_address', 'billing')) {
    $field_instance['widget']['settings']['available_countries'] = array('NZ');
    $field_instance['widget']['settings']['format_handlers']['address-hide-country'] = 'address-hide-country';
    $field_instance['widget']['settings']['format_handlers']['address-hide-postal-code'] = 0;
    $field_instance['widget']['settings']['format_handlers']['address-hide-street'] = 0;
    $field_instance['widget']['settings']['format_handlers']['address-optional'] = 0;
    // The above settings are preserved on save, but this one isn't.
    $field_instance['widget']['settings']['default_country'] = 'NZ';
    field_update_instance($field_instance);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've cross-posted this from https://www.drupal.org/node/2453781 as I suspect I'll get an answer here faster. If so I'm happy to update the d.o issue with the solution (even if it's embarrassing).

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't @rooby - comment in the code today indicates that it didn't work, and there were only three sites to apply it to so I would just have done it manually in the end. Sorry I can't be more help!